# ReferenceError: $ is not defined en Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

El problema sólo me lo da en Firefox, me sale un error: `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. He leído que puede ser un problema de certificado de Firefox, pero no acabo de resolverlo.

```js
var count=0;


$('#invitado').click(function(){
    if(count==0){
      document.getElementById('sesion_popup').style.display='block';
      document.getElementById('invitado').style.color='black';
      document.getElementById('inicio_registro').style.display='none';
      count=1;
    }else{
      document.getElementById('sesion_popup').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('invitado').style.color='blue';
      document.getElementById('inicio_registro').style.display='flex';
      count=0;
    }
  });

  $('#sesion_usuario').click(function(){
    if(count==0){
      document.getElementById('panel_usuario_popup').style.display='block';
      document.getElementById('sesion_usuario').style.color='black';
      document.getElementById('inicio_registro').style.display='none';
      count=1;
    }else{
      document.getElementById('panel_usuario_popup').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('sesion_usuario').style.color='blue';
      document.getElementById('inicio_registro').style.display='flex';
      count=0;
    }
  });
```

```css
.usuario #sesion_popup {
    position: absolute;
    height: 205px;
    background: #fff;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue Regular","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    z-index: 300;
    width: 328px;
    padding-top: 65px;
    padding-left: 39px;
    display: none;
    left: -5px;
    top: -5px;
    box-shadow: .1px .1px 2px #888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sesion">
     <a rel="nofollow" href="#" id="invitado">Invitado</a><div id="inicio_registro"><a class="iniciemos" href="https://www.laxtore.com/Iniciar-Sesion/">Iniciar Sesión</a><a href="https://www.laxtore.com/Registro/">Registrarse</a></div>

</div>

<div id="sesion_popup">
    <a href="">Login avanzado</a>
    <a href="">Registrarse</a>
    <form class="credenciales"  action="<?php echo $ruta ?>" method="post">
         <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario:">
            <input type="password" name="password" value="Contraseña:">
         </div>
         <input class="submit_login" type="submit" name="submit_login" value="►">
      </form>
</div>
```

**EDITO: Estaba cargando javascript de esta forma:**

```
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"  type="text/javascript" async></script>`
```

**Al quitar `async` funciona todo de forma correcta.**

Comment: Fijate si enlazas tu script de buena forma, porque aquí funciona bien

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Lo hago de esta forma `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"  type="text/javascript" async></script>`

Comment: Ese es jquery, me refiero a tu propio código

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Ya está solucionado, el problema me lo estaba dando `async`.

Comment: Ese error suele ocurrir cuando intentes usar jQuery antes de agregar la librería o sin agregarla del todo, debido a un error en la URL o a otros motivos. Atención, lo que cargas ahí **no es Javascript**, sino la librería jQuery. Javascript viene ya cargado, con el navegador, a no ser que lo tengas desactivado, en cuyo caso tampoco jQuery va a funcionar.

Comment: Que bien que lo hayas resuelto, puedes auto-responderte

Comment: @A.Cedano ¡Gracias por la aclaración! Lo he conseguido resolver finalmente.

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo he conseguido resolver modificando la forma en la que estaba incluyendo la librería jQuery. Lo estaba haciendo así:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"  type="text/javascript" async></script>
```

Al eliminar el parámetro `async` ya no me da ningún error en Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas lo mas probable es que estes Usando el **firefox** menor a 3.6 y no tiene soporte para el atributo **async** .

---

### Definición y uso

> El atributo async es un atributo booleano.
>
> Cuando está presente, especifica que el script se ejecutará de manera asíncrona tan pronto como esté disponible.

---

**Nota:** El atributo async es solo para scripts externos (y solo debe usarse si el atributo src está presente).

**Nota:** hay varias formas en que se puede ejecutar un script externo:

- Si async está presente: el script se ejecuta de forma asíncrona con el resto de la página (el script se ejecutará mientras la página continúa el análisis)
- Si async no está presente y el aplazamiento está presente: el script se ejecuta cuando la página ha terminado de analizar
- Si no está presente ni asincrónico ni diferido: el script se busca y se ejecuta inmediatamente, antes de que el navegador continúe analizando la página

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

saludos espero que te ayude.

**Fuente:**
[www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp)